# Evaluate Initialization cells at startup

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, initialization

How can I start an evaluation of the initialization cells when a notebook is opened?
Should I use `FrontEndExecute[]` in some way?

Comment: You can do this with `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateInitialization"]` but note that even if you make this `Dynamic` you will still need to enable `Dynamic` for that notebook before it will work.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Is there a way to automatic enable Dynamic?

Comment: You'll understand that is a security risk, so short of placing the notebook in a trusted directory, no.

Comment: By the way, placing FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateInitialization"] a the beginning of the notebook, cause a "running" loop when i click evaluate initialization cells from the menu

Comment: Oh I thought you knew to place it in the `NotebookDynamicExpression` or similar. Sorry about that.

Comment: @b3m2a1 writing this NotebookDynamicExpression[
  FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateInitialization"]]; , I still have a loop

Comment: `NotebookDynamicExpression` is an option. Please read the documentation. This should not be in a cell as obviously that cell will be evaluated every time you run the initialization, which will re-run the initialization, etc.

Comment: See [search InitializationCellEvaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=InitializationCellEvaluation+) and let us know what is missing.